# flink 1.3 metric / operator naming: Group multiple operations under one name

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to combine multiple map operations on my `dataStream` into one group so that in the metrics / flink dashboard visualization my operator chain `(map -> map -> map)` shows up as `(foo)`. 
Calling `#name` on the last map leaves me with `(map -> map -> foo)` rather than `(foo)`.

Can this be done? I like grouping my logic into map/filter/flatMap blocks and want to avoid rewriting it to fit into a single flatMap just to clean up the metric names.

(flink 1.3)

Comment: I checked the source code, it seems there is no API to set the chained operator's name.

Comment: Thanks! It seems this is a non standard use case and i kinda expected it - didn't even any related questions or mails at all. Oh well :)...

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be:

- You can only name single transformations (operations)
- You **cannot name** an operator chain like `Map -> Map -> Custom Name` to something linke `Chain Name`.